# R data.table Perform Aggregate On Select Rows Using Full Dataset

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I'm calculating features for a machine learning algorithm in R using data.table. I'm only going to be making predictions on rows that have a future date, but to calculate each feature, I need to aggregate on a large dataset that can have millions of rows. However, to improve processing speed and performance, I don't need the aggregate to calculate on rows that are for a past date.

In plain terms, I'm trying to use a large dataset to calculate the feature for only the last *n* rows using the entire dataset and skip rows where the Date is in the past. I have a user defined function that counts the number of rows that are higher than the current row being calculated in the loop. My example data.table below shows the outcome I'm trying to achieve. The row being calculated will count the number of rows higher than it and then move to the next row in the loop. I want it to skip all rows with a past date and only calculate rows with a future date. The current date in this example is `2019-03-20`.

```
Group         Date  Appt  Sum
    A   2019-03-18     1   NA
    A   2019-03-19     1   NA
    A   2019-03-20     1   NA
    A   2019-03-21     1    3
    A   2019-03-22     1    4
    A   2019-03-23     1    5

library(data.table)
dt = structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Date = structure(c(17973, 
17974, 17975, 17976, 17977, 17978), class = "Date"), Appt = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sum = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
setDT(dt)
```

This is the function and code I'm currently using and it works perfectly. The only problem is that it performs the calculation on every row even though I only need the calculation results for a few rows at the end of the dataset that can be in the millions. It's wasting a ton of processing power and time by making calculations that will be excluded from the prediction set.

```
rollingSum <- function(i, data, count, dates) {
  z <- with(data[i, ], zoo(count, dates))
  g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), by="day"))
  m <- merge(z, g)
  window(rollapplyr(m, 365, sum, na.rm=TRUE, partial=TRUE), time(z))
}

dt[, Sum := as.numeric(rollingSum(data=dt, count=Appt, dates=Date) - Appt), by=Group]
```

Comment: Is this just `dat[, sapply(Date, function(x) sum(x > Date)), by=Group]` ?

Comment: How do I insert my user defined function into this solution?

Comment: You don't. I was thinking this replaces the whole function.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it counted on every row still.

Comment: `dat[x:y, sapply(Date, function(x) sum(x > dat$Date)), by=Group]` where `a:b` is the range of rows you want to count?

Comment: My first thought was to use data.table subset to include only the future dates. However, it did correctly aggregate using only the rows I intended, but it also only used those rows in the calculation. For example, if I subsetted and only two rows met the condition, then the calculated values would only be 0 & 1 when there were thousands of rows ahead of it. The correct values should be 40 & 41 because that is the number of rows ahead of each subsetted row that meets the 365 day range in my custom function.

Comment: could this be an alternative for your user function?
`dt[, Sum2 := ifelse(Date > as.IDate("2019-03-20"), (1:.N) - Appt , as.numeric(NA)), by = Group]`

Answer (score 1):

here is some more details for my comment above:

```
dt <- data.table(
  Group = "A",
  Date = as.IDate(c("2019-03-18", "2019-03-19", "2019-03-20",
                    "2019-03-21", "2019-03-22","2019-03-23")),
  Appt = 1)


microbenchmark(
  dt[, Sum := as.numeric(rollingSum(data=dt, count=Appt, dates=Date) - Appt), by=Group],
  dt[, Sum2 := ifelse(Date > as.IDate("2019-03-20"), (1:.N) - Appt , as.numeric(NA)), by = Group],unit = "ms")
```

here are the benchmarks:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq         max neval
 rollingSum 3.463955 4.0644910 18.748804 4.353562 4.745325 1395.840823   100
   new func 0.768079 0.8757095  1.258782 1.015766 1.140316    8.275985   100
```

Comment: Thank you Jakob. This solution is very close. Its counting only the future dates, but it's not respecting the 365 day range restriction in the custom function rollingSum. Its just counting all the records for the same group. The output from the actual data goes 2 years back, but the rollingSum function only counts rows that are less than 365 days from the current row being calculated. In the actual output of my data, Sum = 117 whereas Sum2 = 371 because there are 372 total rows for Group A, but only 117 rows within the 365 day range.

Comment: I see...
After thinking a while, I could only come up with this:
`dt[Date > today - (2 * this_window) - 1, Sum3 := rollapplyr(Appt, this_window, sum, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE) - Appt, by=Group]`
With `this_window <- 365` you should get the same result as in Sum2 for the lines after today. The lines before have wrong results, but those you said you dont need. Also this solution would need that you have merge the missing days into it - which you do anyways within `rollingSum`. I dont know if this is still faster and the calculation is still done on rows you dont need.

Comment: the main idea here would be to use rollapplr not wihtin a UDF but directly within the group by.